# Click event for textbox

Tags: asp.net

There is one column of textbox in my item template. When I run the page and click on the textbox I want an event to fire. How can I make this happen?

Comment: You'll use to hook up to the "onclick" event of your textbox (using JavaScript of just in-line declaration), which runs a JavaScript function calling "_doPostBack" or the relevant ASP.NET function of your system.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do when someone clicks? Odds are it's something you'd be best off processing on the client in JavaScript, possibly using jQuery. JavaScript will happily handle a "textbox" click event, although by the time your textbox hits the browser it's been rendered as an `<input type="text">`.

Think of ASP.Net as being a tool that generates and manipulates HTML, and sends it to/from the browser. ASP.Net events are the result of the browser posting the entire page back to the server, the server doing something to it, and the server sending the whole page back. There's obviously times when that is what you'd want, and times when it's not, I suspect this will be the latter, unless you're doing something data related.

---

To show a div on textbox click, I would use the jQuery Show() and Hide() methods. Create your content in ASP.net, and use 1 jQuery function to hide the div when the page loads (on browser, not server), and another to show them. Have a look at these - http://api.jquery.com/show/ and http://api.jquery.com/hide/ . The examples on that page will translate to what you're after; don't let the ASP.Net thing distract you, by the time your page is on the browser it's in HTML.